# Draw line from HTML table cell to cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, d3.js

I would like to make a nice visual for a floor plan but I'm not finding any Javascript/jQuery libraries to help me achieve this. I have a input which is a text file that contains 0 or 1 (10x10 matrix taken as example), the 1's represents a wall. I read the input and place it into a 2D matrix. I then create an HTML table (10x10 table) where each cell is either coloured in to represent a wall or left blank (not a wall). This does not create a good visual, instead it just looks like coloured in boxed. Is there a better way I can achieve this?

I have looked at this question and many more.

[How to create floor plans that work nice with mobile and desktop browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735718/how-to-create-floor-plans-that-work-nice-with-mobile-and-desktop-browsers)

I have also looked at the D3 library, but it requires you upload base image of the floor plan. Is there any better way I can do this?

Comment: have you tried using canvas?

Comment: @TomásAntunes I have tried using canvas, but the grid is to small. I need to make it a 10x10 or some example size depending on the input. I also use pathingfinding.js library to find a path from one point to another using the 2D matrix. It just doesn't display well in a canvas. I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try this, it probably needs a different config file - http://openfloorplan.org/

Comment: I'm trying to keep the same config file, mainly for proportions.